# Symmetric random walk: prove recurrence

Tags: probability-theory, recurrence-relations, markov-chains, random-walk

Let $X$ be a symmetric random walk on $\mathcal{Z}$ with transition matrix elements
$p(x,y)=1/3$ if $|x-y|\leq1$ and $0$ otherwise.

I know this is a recurrent random walk since the expectation of the jump is zero (see, for example, Theorem 17.41 of Probability Theory by A. Klenke, 3rd version).

**I would like to prove the recurrence of $X$ without the above result**. Thus, I would like to prove that

$$
P_0[\tau^1_0<\infty]=1
$$
where $\tau^1_0=\inf\{n>0: X_n=0\}$ is the first return time.

**My attempt**

Using the Law of Total Probability (first step analysis):
$$
P_0[\tau^1_0<\infty]=\frac{1}{3}P_0[\tau^1_0<\infty|X_1=-1]+\frac{1}{3}P_0[\tau^1_0<\infty|X_1=0]+\frac{1}{3}P_0[\tau^1_0<\infty|X_1=1]
$$

By using the Markov property I obtained
$$
P_0[\tau^1_0<\infty]=\frac{1}{3}P_{-1}[\tau^1_0<\infty]+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}P_{1}[\tau^1_0<\infty]
$$

**How can I continue from here?** I think this is an example of "**recurrent equations**" but I do not know how to set up the system to be solved.

Let me know if more details are needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us now set $u_{k}:=\mathbb{P}\left(\tau_{0}^{1}<\infty\right)$. As you shown,
$$
u_{0}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}u_{1}.
$$
Note that $u_{-1}$ is not here anymore because $u_{1}=u_{-1}$ due to the symetrical behavior of the chain.
But with the same idea you can also show
$$
u_{1}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}u_{1}+\frac{1}{3}u_{2}\text{ and }u_{2}=\frac{1}{3}\left(u_{1}+u_{2}+u_{3}\right)
$$
and more generally, for all $n\geq 2$
$$
u_{n}=\frac{1}{3}\left(u_{n-1}+u_{n}+u_{n+1}\right) \Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}-2u_{n}+u_{n-1}=0.
$$
This is a linear recurrent sequence of order $2$. At the order $2$, it can be solved using the "characteristic equation" given by $x^{2}-2x+1=0$, and this entails that
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients)
$$
u_{n}=A+B(n-1),\forall n\geq 1.
$$
But since $0\leq u_{n}\leq 1$, the above equation for $u_{n}$ can not hold unless $B=0$. So, we get that $u_{n}=A$ for all $n\geq 1$. To conclude, you can for instance remark that, due to the invariance by translation of the model and the strong Markov property, you have $\mathbb{P}_{k}(\tau_{0}<\infty)= \mathbb{P}_{1}(\tau_{0}<\infty)^{k}$, so $1/3\leq A= A^{k}\leq 1$ which cannot be true unless $A=1$.

Comment: Thank you. I am almost there but I have a couple of questions before accepting it. 1) Could you articulate about the fact $B=0$
 as I do not understand (I am new to the topic) where the term $(n−1)$
 comes from? I would put $n$ there. 2) In the last argument, I would conclude that, for $n\geq2$, we have $u_n=A$. Then, inductively, since $A=P_2[\tau^1_0<\infty]=P_2[\tau^1_1<\infty]P_1[\tau^1_0<\infty]=P_1[\tau^1_0<\infty]^2$,$A=P_3[\tau^1_0<\infty]=P_3[\tau^1_2<\infty]P_2[\tau^1_0<\infty]=P_1[\tau^1_0<\infty]^3$ and so on,  I would conlude that $P_1[\tau^1_0<\infty]=1$. Does it hold?

Comment: 1) In fact, it doesn't matter if you put $n$ or $(n-1)$, it just changes the values of the constants: if I say $u_n=C+Dn$, it would imply that $C=A-B$ and $D=B$. 2) Yes, this is it, maybe a little more justification is needed to see how translational invariance and strong Markov property are involved.